# Promo codes link to different pages

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to build a promo code page for users to come to. They would type a promo code in a form box, click submit, then link to the appropriate page.
So for example the promo code "STUDENT" would take them to mysite.com/student, "EASTER" would take them to mysite.com/easter, etc...

I see lots of ways to use JS to link to other pages, but nothing where the input is read, then the link is built to match it.

I'm learning JS, so maybe just looking for a jumpstart...

Thank you

-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the value

```
boxContents = document.getElementById('inputBox').value;
```

and then redirect to that

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/" + boxContents;
```